# IDE setup for huge monorepo from typescript with project references

Tags: typescript

We have a huge monorepo, we have enabled typescript with project references.

For IDE we are seeing regression and slow intellisense with this change.

We have enabled disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect and disableReferencedProjectLoad

But still seeing huge time, what are we missing.